# What is this icon with a square and a waveform in Apple Watch Control Center?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, control-center

I noticed this icon in Control Center on my Apple Watch recently and didn’t recognize it. <s>It’s not listed on Apple’s support pages about Control Center ([a](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206951) [b](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/control-center-apd06bc15da1/watchos))</s>. **UPDATE:** [This page](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/control-center-apd06bc15da1/watchos) now includes this icon.

[image: Screenshot of Control Center on Apple Watch]

(bottom left)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to determine the button’s purpose through VoiceOver, which reads this button as “announce messages”.

Comment: Well done. I was wrong that it controlled sound recognition, thanks for posting so I could learn from that mistake.